# comparing selecteditempostion from spinner to an arraylist with resources

Tags: java, android, arraylist, spinner

This is probably a dumb question but I'm very new to coding so please bear with me.

I am trying to make audiofiles play when a button is pressed and a song is selected in the spinner. But the number doesnt seem to be updating and I only get the same song played.

```
 private void Onclick() {
    final int[] songlist ={
            R.raw.salsa,
            R.raw.fantasy,
    };

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, songlist[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
    mp.setLooping(true);

    play_btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mp.start();}


            });}
```

Why doesnt this work?

EDIT: onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    play_btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_btn);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.song_spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.songs_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);


    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    Onclick();



}
```

Comment: getSelectedItemPosition() is not a method of Spinner class, are you confusing it with a ListView?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
Do you know of any other way to do this then?

Comment: Can you show me the code of spinner property? (declaration and initialization)?

Comment: Thats in my onCreate method: ill edit it in

Comment: i've added an answer based on your update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with this:

add a class property like:

```
final int[] songlist ={
        R.raw.salsa,
        R.raw.fantasy,
};

int selectedSong; //default to 0
```

Then in your class, you can add a listener on spinner value change events with this:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        selectedSong = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {}
});
```

And now in the button onClick, you can go with this code:

```
play_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, songlist[selectedSong]);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I did everything you said but I still got an error. I ended up changing `mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, songlist[selectedsong]);`
to mp = `MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, songlist[selectedsong]);`
and that worked!

Comment: Yeah, obviously you needed to change the context with the class one ;)

Answer (score 0):

To make this work all you have to do is initialise the media-player object every time when you click on the button pressed.

```
play_btn.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // in your code it is initialised with the first selected object
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, songlist[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start();}
        })};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

Comment: I tried this but just got the following error:
cannot resolve method 'create(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener, int)'

Comment: Check the syntax of the method bro